# Google Finance Stock Symbol Recognition

Tags: google-sheets

Google Finance no longer recognizes many stock symbols that they have in the past.  Two examples today,  BXSL and RC and others.  Google Finance web site as well as in Google Sheets report either nothing or incorrect data.  RC is Ready Capital but Google Finance reports it a Royal Caribbean on their website and returns no data on a Google Sheet.  The errors seem to be increasing in the last few weeks. Of course reporting these errors to Google brings no action.

Is Google Finance being fazed out by Google?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue might be temporary instability, but it's worth trying to put the stock exchange's code before the stock ticker symbol.

For example, instead of:

```
=googlefinance("RC")
```

Use:

```
=googlefinance("NYSE:RC")
```

This can bring more accuracy, because different companies in the world can use the same stock symbol, but in different exchanges. Also, it's always good to check if the company changed their stock ticker symbol.